# Trouble with simple Array - Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, arrays, cocoa, syntax-error

I was wondering to know if there is any possibility to do the following:

I have a method like:

```
one = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3", nil];
two  = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"4",@"5",@"6", nil];

-(void)getStringAndChooseArray:(NSString *)nameOfArray {
//What i want to do is something like:
NSLog(@"The array %@ has got %i objects",nameOfArray,[nameOfArray count]) 
//Of course it is giving me an error since nameOfArray is a string..

//I know it is hard to understand,
//but what I'm trying to do is to call this method
//pass a string variable, which is named as one of the two arrays,
//and using it to do the rest..

}
```

How to use a string to identify an array and manipulate it ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I really question the reason you want to do this.

Comment: because of my app, I simplified the problem of course..

I am working with tables and SQL data, but since it is the first time I'm having lot of troubles...

basically i have a table with many SQL tables fields, and need to choose the relative array to the clicked tables..

Pretty hard to explain both for me and for my bad english..
Thanks anyway

Comment: Your English is not that bad. :) Thanks for the background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [dictionary](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to map arrays to strings and then you can use them:

```
one = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3", nil];
two  = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"4",@"5",@"6", nil];
NSDictionary *mapping = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"one",one,@"two",two,nil];

-(void)getStringAndChooseArray:(NSString *)nameOfArray {
  NSArray *array = [mapping objectForKey:nameOfArray];
  NSLog(@"The array %@ has got %i objects",array,[array count]) 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Store your arrays in a dictionary and use the names you want to reference them by as their related keys.